# Read from file and add words to tree efficiently

Tags: c++, readfile, trie

I have a file as input from the Command Arguments. I read each line this way:

```
    vector<string> filewords;
     string line;
     while(getline(cin, line){
       filewords.push_back(line);
     }
```

I haven't found any other way to get the strings from the file, if I could get the whole content in a mega-string that would be great, but I haven't found how

I add the words to the trie this way:

```
    for(const auto &word : *filewords){ 
      if(word.length() >= 3 && word.length() <= 17){
        root->addString(word.c_str());
      }
    }
```

I need to check that each line has certain length before adding it to the trie.
addString is:

```
void Node::addString(const char* word)
{
  if(!mChildren[*word - 'a']) mChildren[*word - 'a'] = new Node(word);
  if(word[1]) mChildren[*word - 'a']->addString(word + 1);
  else mChildren[*word - 'a']->setMarker(true);
}
```

the children are ordered alphabetically so 'a' is in position 0 and so on.

Node is a class with the following constructor:

```
Node::Node(const char* a)
{
  mContent = *a;
  mChildren.resize(26);
}
```

There will be max 26 children (26 letters in the alphabet)

I'm not sure if the little optimizations I've made (making mChildren of size 26, adding each line to a vector and then iterating through this vector ...) are actually worth it or if there's a better way.

I'm suppossed to make this part of program last ~80ms, and right now it takes ~120ms with a file consisting of ~180.000 words.

Any ideas on how to optimize / reduce complexity / improve the code? Thanks!

Comment: How do you measure the time? Have you tried measuring or profiling the different parts of the code, to see where the bottlenecks are? And if you check [a good input stream reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) you might find some method of [reading larger chunks](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

Comment: Also, you do know that `std::getline` reads a whole *line* not a single word? That will only work if each line is a single word.

Comment: Forgot to mention sorry, each ilne is always a word. I can't use any other input stream reference apart from cin, because the filename is in the Command Arguments. Regarding the time, I put a clock before and after these operations and get the difference.I have no idea where to put the clocks in the inner functions since these will be executed 180000 times. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not mention that you have any other use for that vector, whatsoever.

Reading ~180,000 lines into a vector first, and then iterating over the vector afterwards, is going to waste a lot of time, and memory, for no apparent value-added.

You should simply insert your words into the trie, as part of reading them.

```
 string word;

 while(getline(cin, word){
  if(word.length() >= 3 && word.length() <= 17){
    root->addString(word.c_str());
  }
 }
```

Comment: I've found that it's faster this way, for whatever reason. Thanks anyway!